# Redirecting mysite.com/somepage/thispage.php to www.mysite.com/somepage/thispage.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried doing this

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mysite.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but when i go to mysite.com, it took me to http://www.mysite.com/mysite. So I removed the $1 and that seemed to fix the issue.

But now that when I go to mysite.com/somepage/thispage.php, it does not work and shows the page not found (the www.mysite.com actually points to where the site is hosted, thats why I want mysite.com to go to www.mysite.com). How can I redirect that to mysite.com/somepage/thispage.php and also the other anything appended to mysite.com?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirects all non-www url's to www.

Comment: BAD idea in general -- what if he has another subdomain, like `secure.mysite.com`? Using your rule it will be redirected to `www.secure.mysite.com`. But yes -- if `www.` is the ONLY available subdomain, then it is OK.